# Build application with client custom theme

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've an application with a default theme (`less` files defined in `app/sytles` and included in `app.less`) and reachable at my main website (for example `http://www.example.com`)

Now I need to build the same application for different clients. Each client has its own style customization (`client.less` file) and its own assets (images, fonts, ...). This site will be deployed at, for example, `http://client1.example.com`.

My idea was to customize the build process passing an additional flag to the `ember build --environment production` command and customize the build process adding the `client.less` file when needed.
Something like `ember build --environment production --theme client1` but as far as I can see there isn't the possibility to pass extra flags to `build` command.
Am I missing something? There is a better way to achieve that? Any help is really appreciate, I wouldn't maintain one project for each client.

Comment: How are your files being served?

Comment: The application will be deployed in apache but I'm opened to any better and working solution

Comment: My gut reaction is that the easiest solution might be to dynamically serve your `index.html` file, and add a reference to an extra CSS file on a per-client basis

Comment: Maybe create client addons (create a base addon and customize for each client) and then manage switching between them with branches in git/hg?

Comment: @alexlafroscia I don't like that because it would mean modify the index.html manually for every client.

Comment: @steveax can you explain a bit more your idea?

Comment: @GUL that's probably going to be a lot less work than modifying the Ember CLI to change the `build` command...